# Dynamic Programming algorithm for assigning workers to tasks

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Let's say you are tasked with assigning m workers to n tasks. You were able to figure out how much "benefit" an ith worker would bring to task j. Or more formally: you have an array A_j[0..m] for each task where A_j[i] is the benefit obtained from having i workers assigned to task j. We can assume that A_j[i] is nondecreasing with increasing i.

I'm trying to design a dynamic programming algorithm to determine how many workers you should assign to each project such that the total benefit obtained over all projects is maximized.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out how to approach this since the "subproblems" seem completely unrelated to each other (the answer to one doesn't inform the answer to another). For example, given this "test case" I made up:

[image]

- If given 3 people, the max benefit, B, would be: B = 15 = T4_1 + T2_2
- If given 4 people,: B = 100 = T1_4

The brute force approach would require exponential time since each time you are given a worker, you have n possible tasks as an option to assign them to. Given my test example, 1 worker could be assigned in 4 possible ways. 2 workers could be assigned in 16 possible ways. 3 in 64, etc. Thus, brute force complexity is O(n^m).

I usually prefer to use a tabulation strategy, rather than memoization, when solving dynamic programming (DP) problems. **Is there a way to build an array to solve this problem using a DP tabulation approach?**

Comment: So, the input to your algorithm is table A, where T[i][j] gives the profit from assigning i workers to the jth project. Also, the input contains n, which is the maximum number of workers to use, and m which is the total number of projects. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I believe so. All the problem information is given in the first paragraph. The rest of the question is my own speculations/interpretations. So they could be wrong I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state of the dynamic programming algorithm is *DP[i][j]*, which means the maximum profit you can gain from assigning *i* workers to the first *j* projects.

Let's take a look at the pseudocode of such an algorithm:

```
int DP[m+1][n+1] = { 0 };
for(int i = 1; i <= m; i++){
    for(int j = 1; j <= n; j++){
        // try to assign k workers to the jth project
        for(int k = 1; k <= i; k++){
            DP[i][j] = max(DP[i][j], profit[k][j] + DP[i - k][j - 1]);
        }
    }
}
```

First, we create the dynamic programming array of size *nxm*. Next, we loop over all possible values of *i* and *j*.

For each pair *i* and *j*, we need to calculate the best profit from assigning *i* workers to the first *j* projects. In order to calculate this, we should try to assign *k* workers to the *jth* project. If we assign *k* workers to the *jth* project, then we need to use *profit[k][j]* which represents the profit from using *k* workers on the *jth* project.

In addition, we need to add the value of *DP[i - k][j - 1]* which represents the best benefit from using *i-k* workers (if we used *k* workers, then we have *i-k* workers left) on the first *j-1* projects.

Once finished, you can get the maximum profit from using *w* workers by checking the value of *DP[w][n]*.

The time complexity of this approach is *O(nxmxm)*, and the space complexity is *O(nxm)*.

Note that we can enhance this approach to have a time complexity of *O(nxm)* by doing some calculations to get rid of the third *for* loop.

Comment: When j is 1, isnt DP[i - k][j - 1] going to be out of bounds?

Comment: I updated my answer and increased the size of the array. In this answer, I assumed that the array is zero-based indexed.